# How to solve input format problem on Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training CNN using Keras. Model architecture is like following:

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=(150, 150, 3),padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2),strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2),strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2,2),padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2),strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Compiling and fitting part of the model is:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),metrics=['acc'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,target_size=(150, 150),batch_size=20, class_mode='binary')
val_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(val_dir,target_size=(150, 150),batch_size=20,class_mode='binary')


history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=30,validation_data=val_generator,validation_steps=50)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
  warnings.warn('`Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and '
2021-07-10 13:04:09.841898: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
Epoch 1/30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/dog_vs_cat/model.py", line 33, in <module>
    history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=30,validation_data=val_generator,validation_steps=50)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1932, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1158, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 950, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3024, in __call__
    filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1961, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 596, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Default MaxPoolingOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU
     [[node sequential/max_pooling2d/MaxPool (defined at \Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\pooling.py:355) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1187]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential/max_pooling2d/MaxPool:
 sequential/conv2d/Relu (defined at \Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py:4700)

Function call stack:
train_function


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have searched and it was advised to use `data_format="channels_last"` as input shape, which I am using. Then I changed input shape to **(3,150,150)** with `data_format="channels_first"`, it still give the same error.

I am using Keras 2.4.3.

Any help?

Comment: What you have used as an input layer?

Comment: model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=(150, 150, 3),padding='same'))
Looks like I left out the most important layer while writing question.

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? else, can try to execute in standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine, when I replicated the same issue in keras version 2.4.3

Working Sample code:

```
!pip install keras==2.4.3
import keras

model = Sequential()
#add model layers
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=(150, 150, 3),padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2),strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2),strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2,2),padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2),strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_directory,target_size=(150, 150),batch_size=5, class_mode='binary')
val_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(Val_directory ,target_size=(150, 150),batch_size=5,class_mode='binary')
#Modified
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=RMSprop(),metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(train_generator,epochs=4,steps_per_epoch=4,validation_data=val_generator,validation_steps=50)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/4
4/4 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0794 - acc: 0.7500WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 50 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
4/4 [==============================] - 4s 753ms/step - loss: 1.0794 - acc: 0.7500 - val_loss: 1.4395 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 2/4
4/4 [==============================] - 1s 348ms/step - loss: 0.3407 - acc: 0.8500
Epoch 3/4
4/4 [==============================] - 1s 349ms/step - loss: 0.6352 - acc: 0.7500
Epoch 4/4
4/4 [==============================] - 1s 357ms/step - loss: 0.3096 - acc: 0.9000
```